# Difference between importing CSS from local files versus remote location into HTML doc

Tags: html, css, import

Hi I'm learning HTML/CSS andI'm wondering what the difference is between *importing CSS from local files versus importing CSS from remote locations into an HTML document* and what would that look like?

So far from what I believe and my understanding is when you *import a CSS file from your local files* is where
you'd add the    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="mycssfilename.css">`    in the HTML document under the `<head>` tag, and should link to your style sheet you created in a code editor.

*Importing CSS file from a remote location* would be where you would add this code under the `<head>` tag `<link href="https://www.yourdomain.com/foldername/styles.css">` for example and that would come from somewhere where it is stored on the web?

Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm just confused between the two. Thank you so much.

Comment: There really isn't much of a difference between importing css files from your local machine vs a remote server. Both should include the `rel="stylesheet"` regardless of whether remote or local. The only reason you need to include the full url when pulling the css from a remote server is because the file isn't located on the server and must know which server to pull the data from. Really the difference you are talking about is between relative vs absolute paths. When pulling files from a remote server they are always absolute paths, but when pulling a local file, a relative path can be used.

Comment: See here for more details between absolute and relative file paths: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/path.html (the link is for Java but the same ideas apply)